# Overloaded operator for accessing member array elements in cpp: performance

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, operator-overloading

I have written a simple Matrix class for easier access to individual data-array elements. It holds information in a standard array and individual elements are returned via an overloaded brackets operator (), however, it seems like the overloaded () operator on the class object is significantly slower than standard [] call on a data array. Class code at the bottom of the post.

I thought that the overloaded operator (i, j) will the same as calling [i * ncols + j] on data array, however, after running some tests, it is about three times slower. I have tested the theory on two simple functions:

```
void square_array(double * data_array, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
    {
        data_array[i * ncols + j] = data_array[i * ncols + j] * data_array[i * ncols + j];
    }
}

void square_mymatrix(MyMatrix & data_mymatrix, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
    {
        data_mymatrix(i, j) = data_mymatrix(i, j) * data_mymatrix(i, j);
    }
}
```

By calling them with 1000x1000 arrays

```
// Define and fill data_array
square_array(data_array, rowsN, colsN);

// Define and fill data_mymatrix
square_mymatrix(data_mymatrix, rowsN, colsN);
```

And the second function call took three times as long as the first one (~4.1ms vs ~11.9ms). Why is that accessing data through the brackets operator is so much slower than using []? Have I made a mistake somewhere in the code?

Below is the code for MyMatrix class.

```
class MyMatrix
{
    double * data;
    int nrows;
    int ncols;

    public:
        // Standard constructur prividing a pre-existant array
        MyMatrix(double * data_array, int rows, int cols)
        {
            this->nrows = rows;
            this->ncols = cols;
            this->data = data_array;
        }
        //Empty constructor
        MyMatrix() {}

        //Simple functions to obtain rows and cols of the matrix
        int get_nrows() {return this->nrows;}
        int get_ncols() {return this->ncols;}

        // Overloaded bracket operator to access the values
        double & operator()(int i, int j) {return data[i * ncols + j];}

        // Overloaded bracket operator for constant objects:
        const double & operator()(int i, int j) const {return data[i * ncols + j];}
};
```

Comment: When asking about performance, it always helps to specify your compiler, its version and the options you are passing to it.

Comment: I am using 
gcc v 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
with: -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra

Comment: Any change if you add `-O3`?

Comment: I have just used the default optimization (-O0), however, after applying -O2 or O3 the difference in performance between two methods becomes negligible. 
Thank you for your comments, I never realised that optimisation levels can have such a different effect on two different implementations.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-O2` or `-O3` to invoke GCC with a higher optimisation level. This should correctly inline the function call to `operator()` and produce binary code equal to the one which accesses the data directly.